# How do I stop this event listener from automatically firing

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've got this self-executing function, which adds event listeners to a series of links. But the event listeners are automatically firing when the page loads, as opposed to onmouseover/out. Have I got the syntax wrong? How do I stop them autofiring?

```
;(function(){
    var menuLink = $('.navItem');
    var menuItem = $('.menuLinks');
    for (a = 0; a <= 5; ++a) {
        menuLink[a].addEventListener('onmouseover', linkChanger(), true);
        menuLink[a].addEventListener('onmouseout', linkChanger(), true);
    }   

    function linkChanger(event){
        if (menuItem[a].style.color == "white") {
            console.log("This is white")
            menuItem[a].style.color = "black";
        }
        else {
            console.log("This is black");
            menuItem[a].style.color = "white";
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menuLink[a].addEventListener('onmouseover', linkChanger, true);
menuLink[a].addEventListener('onmouseout', linkChanger, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write linkChanger(), it is executing the function and giving the result to the Listener. Either wrap it with `function() { linkChanger(); }` or replace with `linkChanger`. The first option allows you to pass arguments and run other functions too.